# Magento 2.1 not displaying out of stock items for configurable items

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-community

I have my store where I created multiple configurable products all with a custom attribute Color and a custom attribue Size. 
In the configuration the 'Display out of Stock Products' is set to yes. For simple products, it is correctly showing the products as out of stock. However for configurable items, I do not see the colors and sizes that are not in stock.
For example, for https://dev.skadi-outdoor.com/montane-configurable-test.html, I have also a product in S(mall) and XL(Extra Large), but those swatches are not showing.
Don't know what I'm doing wrong? Any related post on this topic that I can find is about the other way around, where people do not want to show these unavailable configured items... 
(UPDATE) I created now also another configurable product with only 1 attribute Size (to exclude that it has to do something with having multiple attributes). This product (https://dev.skadi-outdoor.com/test-omm.html) has 6 sizes, 3 with stock and 3 without, but only the ones with stock are showing ???

Answer (score 0):

This is a default Magento 2 setting. Out of stock simple products that are associated with a configurable product do not show on the configurable product's page.

We had to create a complete customization to show out of stock simple products on a configurable product page.

Comment: Thanks, I had the impression that lots of people complained because it showed those simple products associated with a configurable product anyway, while they didn't want this.
Any suggestions on how to start the customization?